# Signing a Ledger Transaction with python

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, python, sol, ledger-nano

I keep getting the Error: Invalid Status 6a80, and I have a hard time figuring out why.
I am able to collect the publicKeys, but I unfortunately can't get signatures through it.
any help will be much appreciated.

```
BIP32_HARDENED_BIT = ((1 << 31) >> 0)
def _harden(n):
    return (n | BIP32_HARDENED_BIT) >>0 


def _extend_and_serialize_multiple_derivations_paths(derivations_paths: List[bytes]):
    serialized: bytes = len(derivations_paths).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little')
    for derivations_path in derivations_paths:
        serialized += derivations_path
    return serialized

class ledgerDongle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dongle = getDongle(debug=False)

    def get_derive_path(self, account = None, change = None):
        length = 0
        if type(account) == int:
            if type(change) == int:
                length = 4
            else:
                length = 3
        else:
            length = 2
        derivation_path = length.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
        derivation_path += _harden(44).to_bytes(4, 'big')
        derivation_path += _harden(501).to_bytes(4, 'big')
        if length > 2:
            derivation_path += _harden(account).to_bytes(4, 'big')
            if length == 4:
                derivation_path += _harden(change).to_bytes(4, 'big')
        return derivation_path

    
    def sign(self, message, offsets: List[int], accept=True):
        assert len(message) <= 65535, "Message to sign is too long"
        derivation_paths = [self.get_derive_path(offset) for offset in offsets]
        header: bytes = _extend_and_serialize_multiple_derivations_paths(derivation_paths)     # + len(message).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')

        max_size = MAX_CHUNK_SIZE - len(header)
        message_splited = [message[x:x+max_size] for x in range(0, len(message), max_size)]
        message_splited_prefixed = [header + s for s in message_splited]

        if len(message_splited_prefixed) > 1:
            final_p2 = P2_EXTEND
            for m in message_splited_prefixed[:-1]:
                data = struct.pack(">BBBBB", LEDGER_CLA, INS_SIGN_MESSAGE, P1_CONFIRM, P2_MORE | P2_EXTEND, len(m)) + m
                self.dongle.exchange(data)
        else:
            final_p2 = 0

        data = struct.pack(">BBBBB", LEDGER_CLA, INS_SIGN_MESSAGE, P1_CONFIRM, final_p2, len(message_splited_prefixed[-1])) + message_splited_prefixed[-1]
        print(data)
        response = self.dongle.exchange(data)

        return response

la = ledgerDongle()
print(la.sign(b'helloword', [0]))
```